# Pass a trigger function to two components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is what i want to do:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Child onTrigger={xxx} />

            <button onClick={xxx} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

When `button` is clicked, I want something to happen in `Child`. How do I do this? It cannot just be a boolean because it should be a trigger and be called multiple times.

Comment: It depends on what your "something" is.  It would help if you could describe what you're trying to accomplish in more specific terms.

Comment: @Ryan I literally want to fire a series of action when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got two options

1º Add a counter to your parent state and increment it everytime you click the button.

2º Add a ref to your child and trigger the function using `this.refs.child.yourFunctionHere()`

Something like this

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
          this.handleClickWithRef = this.handeClickWithRef.bind(this);
          this.state = {
                triggerEvent: 0
          };
        }

        handleClick(e) {
          this.setState({
            triggerEvent: this.state.triggerEvent+1
          });
        }
        handeClickWithRef(e){
            this.refs.child.functionA();
        }

        render() {
            return <div>
                <Child ref="child" onTrigger={this.state.triggerEvent} /> 
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to trigger</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClickWithRef}>Click to trigger using ref</button>
                </div>;
        }
}
class Child extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
        }
        functionA(){
           alert("With ref");
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
                if(nextProps.onTrigger !== 0 && nextProps.onTrigger !== this.props.onTrigger){
                alert("Your event here");
            }
        }
        render(){
           return <div>Child Component</div>
        }
}
```

[full working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/626/)

Comment: Cool! That's interesting. Didn't think of that :p

Comment: You can also add a ref attribute to your child and call the functions from there, I edited the answer and the jsfiddle.